# How to use keycodes in an array to filter which keys are taken as input within a 'keyup' event listener?

Tags: javascript, arrays, validation, input, keycode

I am trying to build a wordle clone, but I am running into issues when trying to filter out only the alphabet to be taken as keyboard inputs for the game.

Currently I have a Keyboard container that contains each row (of class 'row') of keys (of class 'key') and a start to a JS file that I cannot seem to move forwards in:

```
// Keyboard
// Listen for key being released
let key_codes = [81,87,69,82,84,89,85,73,79,80,
                  65,83,68,70,71,72,74,75,76,
                  13,90,88,67,86,66,78,77,8];
document.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode in key_codes) {
        console.log(e.keyCode);
    }
});
```

I have made a list of all the acceptable keycodes for the game, and have tried to add an event listener to watch for keys being released but when I check 'if (e.keyCode in key_codes)' I don't get an output when I should be.

I have checked the types of the list elements and the keyCodes (they match) and have tried printing 'e.keyCode' before that if statement, and it correctly prints whichever key I press.

I may be missing something obvious here but somehow I am unable to figure this one out for myself.

Comment: `if (e.keyCode in key_codes)` that's not how you check if a thing is in an array.  `if (key_codes.includes(e.keyCode))`

Comment: Please read the red box on [`keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) documentation!

Answer (score 0):

That is not how you use the `in` keyword in javascript, `in` is used to check if an object has a specific property in it, this will work in python but not in this case
[Read more about in keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)

how you can achieve this is by using `Array.prototype.includes` function, it checks for the first occurence of an element in an array and returns true if it exists else returns false

```js
let key_codes = [81,87,69,82,84,89,85,73,79,80,
                  65,83,68,70,71,72,74,75,76,
                  13,90,88,67,86,66,78,77,8];
document.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    if (key_codes.includes(e.keyCode)) {
        console.log(`${e.keyCode} is in array`);
    } else console.log(`${e.keyCode} not in array`);
});
```

Run the above code and test it yourself